# Decompressing PVRTC

Tags: c#, c++

### Task

For my own OpenGL-Framework i'm trying to decompress PVRTC textures when the plattform isn't supporting it. For this i've downloaded the [PVRTC-SDK](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp) and translated the C++-code 1:1 into C#-code with unmanaged code.

### Problem

To make things short: It isn't working and i don't know the reason for it. I've checked the code twice and it seems to be ok and should work. <strike>Sometimes i get a `AccessViolationException`, sometimes a `LoaderLock`.</strike> The `AccessViolationException` is not longer occuring, has been a error in another part of my code. The colors of the PVRTC is still wrong. It Looks strange, basic strokes are visible, but the colors are wrong.

### Code

Because of the reason that the code is huge i uploaded it:

[C#]  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2a65

[C++] http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2a66

Also the calling code of the C# method, the sizes actually matches the expected values ( So the image values for the source array is exactly `width * height * 4bit` and the output size is `width * height * 4byte` ( so the 8x size of the compressed image ).

```
private static unsafe Image ConvertPVRTC_RGBA8888(Image source)
{
    Int32 mipmapCount = source.HasMipmaps ? Image.GetMipmapCount(source.Width, source.Height) : 1;
    // Create a array with bytes for the target format
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[RGBA8.GetMipMappedSize(0, mipmapCount, source.Width, source.Height)];


    fixed (Byte* pTarget = bytes)
    {
        fixed (Byte* pSource = source.GetData())
        {
            Int32 sourceOffset = 0;
            Int32 targetOffset = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < mipmapCount; i++)
            {
                // Calculate offsets
                Int32 sourceSize = source.Format.GetMipMappedSize(i, 1, source.Width, source.Height);
                Int32 targetSize = RGBA8.GetMipMappedSize(i, 1, source.Width, source.Height);

                // Decompress mipmapLevel
                PVRTC.DecompressPVRTC(pSource + sourceOffset, pTarget + targetOffset, GetMipmapSize(source.Width, i), GetMipmapSize(source.Height, i), source.Format.BitsPerPixel == 2);

                // Calculate pointer offset
                sourceOffset += sourceSize;
                targetOffset += targetSize;
            }
        }
    }
    return new Image(bytes, ImageFormat.RGBA8, source.Width, source.Height, source.HasMipmaps, source.IsCubemap);
}
```

### Thoughts

Either the original source-code is not correct or i missed something when i translated the code. Anyway i need a solution and checked the source code twice.

( If there would be any source code for C# i would use it, but i can't find any )

Comment: Have you tried running the original C# code?

Comment: @RQDQ The original code is C++, and it should work, i mean it's the official sdk!

Comment: I was just going off of "Either the original source-code is not correct"...  If you run that code with your data, you can eliminate the original source code as the problem.

Comment: As I don't know C#, can you post an image or two of the results of the two code snippets? That might help to get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: @SimonF I already managed to solve the problem right now, but i don't know why. Wanted to remove the question but this is not possible with an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the [links to codeviewer.org no longer work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345443/what-should-happen-to-questions-using-codeviewer-org-for-sharing-code). Without these links, the question has no clear [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @g00glen00b Would love to even delete this question.

Comment: @FelixK. I personally don't think this question has any value towards other readers due to the missing code and the answer being fairly boad, so unless you can retrieve the old code and edit into the question I think deleting is a good idea. However, I don't think you can delete this post since it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @g00glen00b I know, i tired it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

**Divide and Conquer**

In the case of translating code, I suggest incrementally testing the code.  If you can provide the same data to the same pieces of code (starting with the most simplistic methods), you can determine where the problem is.

**Type Sizes**

Be aware that a long in C# might not be the same thing as a long in C++.  Note that I haven't looked at your code to see if this is an issue in your case (too much work).

**Calling Conventions**

When calling unsafe code in .NET, you might have to specify the calling method (how parameters are pushed onto and removed from the stack).  These are things we don't have to worry about in a pure .NET solution because it's all the same.

Comment: Helped me with another issue, so you'll get a +1 when i got later any answer which helps me.

Comment: Could you remove this answer? This question has no value anymore.